# Determining the size of a file pointed by a symbolic link under the OS X sandbox

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, nsfilemanager

To determine the size of a file, I have always used:

```
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];
unsigned long long size = [fileAttributes fileSize];
```

However, the method `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` *does not traverse symbolic links*. Apple so suggests:

> If the item at the path is a symbolic link—that is, the value of the `NSFileType` key in the attributes dictionary is `NSFileTypeSymbolicLink`—you can use the `destinationOfSymbolicLinkAtPath:error:` method to retrieve the path of the item pointed to by the link.

This would be great, if the sandbox does not prevent me from accessing the pointed file:

> deny file-read-xattr `/path/to/the/original/file`

So, my question is: how can I obtain the size of a file pointed by a symbolic link under the OS X sandbox?

Comment: Is the file that the symlink points to outside of your sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. If the user has specifically dragged a symlink to the app, that's a clear statement of user intent and you'd expect to have access to the symlink and the target. In fact, I can access the original file and read its contents, but not *its attributes*. So I filed the bug report #13143810.

**EDIT:** My bug report has been closed as duplicate of #12991152, which is actually "open."